# Crear archivos backup por tiempo en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo un archivo JSON en la cual quiero crear una serie de copias de seguridad en un periodo de 5 minutos, en este momento, tengo un programa funcionando con NodeJS que lee y escribe un archivo definido por:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

Pero me he dado cuenta de que cuando mi programa obtiene un error inesperado y se cierra repentinamente, deja el archivo "abierto" y se borra todo el contenido. Lo que me gustaría hacer es una función en la que cada periodo, guarde todo el contenido del archivo **./points.json** y que tras haberlo escrito y guardado, que lo cierre (así si el programa "crashea", no se borra el contenido) y al siguiente autoguardado, crear otro archivo nuevo.

Preferentemente, las copias de seguridad deberían ser "points"+timestamp.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: en situaciones similares yo uso `crontab` en linux o Windows Schedule Manager en ... Windows. Un task `cron` te puede ejecutar tu script `node make_backup.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs es quien hace el proceso de guardado de archivos, ajeno al tiempo en que se haga, teniendo el mismo problema ya sea en el proceso habitual en que se esta realizando el proceso o en el momento en que se haga el backup,

Yo sugeriria que usara algo como redis

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

https://redis.io/

Esto te permitira guardar datos en memoria fuera del programa, cosa que si se cierra el programa, pueda ir cuando el programa abra de nuevo en cualquier momento a recuperar la informacion, lo mas importante es que trate de controlar las excepciones del programa suyo para evitar que se cierre

Comment: Vale, he visto algunos desarrolladores de alto nivel en NodeJS usando tanto Bluebird como Node-Redis, pero no sabía muy bien para qué servían, echaré un vistazo, que **DiscordJS** (una librería que estoy usando para un bot) usa también el nombre *client* (aunque actualmente lo he definido como *bot*).

Gracias por su sugerencia